# Count Distinct Over partition

Tags: sql-server, windows, function

I try this code with windows function but I'm getting an error 
All I want is to count distinct customerID based on partition summary and details -- it looks I'm missing something in the over partition 
(SQL Server 2016)

Thanks,
Oded Dror

Code goes here:

```
Drop table if exists #T_Test
Create table #T_Test(
     [Type] varchar(50) null,
     SubType varchar(50) null,
     CustomerID int null
)
Insert into #T_Test ([Type],[SubType],[CustomerID]) values
('TypeA','SubTypeA',390),
('TypeA','SubTypeA',107),
('TypeB','SubTypeB',3),
('TypeB','SubTypeC',3),
('TypeB','SubTypeB',107),
('TypeB','SubTypeC',107),
('TypeB','SubTypeB',390),
('TypeB','SubTypeC',390),
('TypeB','SubTypeC',718),
('TypeB','SubTypeB',100120),
('TypeB','SubTypeC',100120),
('TypeB','SubTypeC',100120),
('TypeC','SubTypeD',107),
('TypeC','SubTypeE',100120),
('TypeC','SubTypeE',718)

--Total goes here - If CustomerID appears in multiple partition it will count once
Select ' Grand Total' as [Type],
              '' as SubType,
              Count(Distinct CustomerID ) as TotalCustomers,
              Count(CustomerID) over (partition by CustomerID,Type Order by CustomerID) as TotalType,
              Count(CustomerID) over (partition by CustomerID,Type,SubType Order by CustomerID) as TotalSubType
From #T_Test

Union All
-- Details goes here - same as Total if customer appers in multiple partiotion it will count once
Select  [Type],
        SubType,
        Count(Distinct CustomerID) as TotalCustomers,
        Count(CustomerID) over (partition by CustomerID,Type Order by CustomerID) as TotalType,
        Count(CustomerID) over (partition by CustomerID,Type,SubType Order by CustomerID) as TotalSubType
From     #T_Test
Group by Type,
         SubType
```

Comment: P.S. The Customer works just fine the problem with Type and SubType

Comment: What is the final output for the input you have given?

Comment: Post the expected result, seems like you are looking for `Group by..with Rollup`

Comment: Total Customers            Total Type    Total SubType
Grand Total                            4                               4                    4
TypeName   SubType             2                                2                  2
                                                 1                               1                  1
                                                  4                               4                  4
                                                   1                              1                    1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        [Type],
        SubType,
        TotCnt= COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY [Type]),
        TotSubCnt= COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY [Type],SubType),
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Type],SubType,[CustomerID] ORDER BY [Type],SubType)
        FROM #T_Test
)
SELECT
    [Type],
    SubType,
    TotCnt,
    TotSubCnt,
    DistCustomer = SUM(CASE WHEN RN =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY [Type])
    FROM CTE
```

Comment: The sum is not accurate you count the partition not the customers

Comment: I'm counting the distinct customers for each Type and Sub Type. If you just need the Distinct Customers only, then remove the Type and Sub Type from the Partition by for Column RN

Comment: Jayasurya,

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
--I hope Customerid is no need to group by

Select ISNULl([Type],'GRAND TOTAL')[Type],
       ISNULL([SubType],'=') as [SubType],
       COUNT(CustomerID) as SubTotal,
       COUNT(distinct CustomerID) AS TotalCustomers 
  FROM #T_test GROUP BY ROLLUP([Type],[SubType]) ORDER BY [Type],[SubType] DESC
```